# Почему может на работать правило ЧПУ в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, url, чпу

есть правило в urlrewrite.php

```
1 =>
        array (
            'CONDITION' => '#^/news/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/#',
            'RULE' => 'ELEMENT_CODE=$1',
            'ID' => '',
            'PATH' => '/news/detail.php',
            'SORT' => 100,
        ),
```

есть физически папка /news и файл detail.php

в настройке URL-страниц компонента news , прописанно `#ELEMENT_CODE#`

то есть по адресу `mysite.com/news/odna_novost` я должен попасть  в файл detail.php, но это правило не срабатывает, и я вижу страницу 404.

Причем все остальные правила из файла urlrewrite.php работают.

Пробывал поднимать правило выше в файле. Сейчас оно первое в массиве , все равно не помогает. Что можно сделать?

Comment: `odna_novost` содержит `_`, а регулярка - нет.

Comment: @u_mulder не в этом дело

Comment: Проверьте еще что слеш есть закрывающий. В регулярке он есть, а в урле нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если добавить нижнее подчёркивание в регулярку то всё работает:

```
'CONDITION' => '#^/news/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/#',
```

Но при условии что в УРЛе есть слеш в конце `mysite.com/news/odna_novost/`

Если слеш в конце УРЛа вам не нужен то уберите его из регулярки:

```
'CONDITION' => '#^/news/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)#'
```

На сайте рекомендуется использовать одну логику: либо у всех страниц есть слеш в конце либо нет. Так не будет путаницы и не будет дублей страниц в поисковых системах.

Как вариант, чтобы у всех страниц добавлялся на конце слеш `/` необходимо добавить в файл `.htaccess` следующие строки:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/[^/\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: да имеено из-за слэша и не работало, благодарю